# Persisting form data after post expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express.js application and I would like to know how I can persist form data *(text area)* after a post request without using **AJAX**.

I hope I am not vague. Thanks in advance.

Comment: res.locals expressjs

Answer (score 1):

The default value of a `textarea` is the child text node inside it. Copy the data into there, and put it in the response you make to the submission request:

```
<textarea name="foo">HTML escaped copy of the previously submitted foo</textarea>
```

Comment: how do i solve this problems for other types of inputs?

Comment: @Deant — value, checked and selected attributes.